# Create a text file and write to it

Tags: vb.net

I want to create a text file and write some text into this file, but my code cannot create the text file.

Error message:

```
    UnauthorizedAccessExcepion was unhandled by user code
 Access to the path 'c:\save.txt' is denied.
```

My code:

```
 Dim fileLoc As String = "c:\save.txt"
                    Dim fs As FileStream = Nothing
                    If (Not File.Exists(fileLoc)) Then
                        fs = File.Create(fileLoc)
                        Using fs

                        End Using
                    End If
                    If File.Exists(fileLoc) Then
                        Using sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(fileLoc)
                            a = "Test: " + TextBox1.Text
                            c = "=============================================="
                            sw.Write(a)
                            sw.Write(c)
                        End Using
                    End If
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In more recent version of Windows, the root of the C: drive is read-only by default. Try putting the file in another folder.

Comment: it work! :] Also, how can create the txt file in My Documents file??

Comment: `SaveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);`

Comment: Dim fileLoc As String = SaveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory + "\save.txt"  ??

Comment: @Kwan Dim fileLoc As String = Environment.GetFolder Path(Environment.SpecialFold er.MyDocuments) & "\save.txt"

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting a little obsessive and want to write to the C drive directory directly, you can use this:

```
Imports System.Security.Principal

Module VistaSecurity

    'Declare API
    Private Declare Ansi Function SendMessage Lib "user32.dll" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As Integer, ByVal wMsg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As String) As Integer
    Private Const BCM_FIRST As Int32 = &H1600
    Private Const BCM_SETSHIELD As Int32 = (BCM_FIRST + &HC)

    Public Function IsVistaOrHigher() As Boolean
        Return Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major < 6
    End Function

    ' Checks if the process is elevated
    Public Function IsAdmin() As Boolean
        Dim id As WindowsIdentity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()
        Dim p As WindowsPrincipal = New WindowsPrincipal(id)
        Return p.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator)
    End Function

    ' Add a shield icon to a button
    Public Sub AddShieldToButton(ByRef b As Button)
        b.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.System
        SendMessage(b.Handle, BCM_SETSHIELD, 0, &HFFFFFFFF)
    End Sub

    ' Restart the current process with administrator credentials
    Public Sub RestartElevated()
        Dim startInfo As ProcessStartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo()
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = True
        startInfo.WorkingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory
        startInfo.FileName = Application.ExecutablePath
        startInfo.Verb = "runas"
        Try
            Dim p As Process = Process.Start(startInfo)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return 'If cancelled, do nothing
        End Try
        Application.Exit()
    End Sub

End Module
```